# converting byte stream in HTTPResponse body into a pdf file

Tags: java, spring, pdf

When i hit an API through postman i am able to download a pdf file.
When i hit the same API through java code i get pdf content in ResponseBody.
And i am able to create a new pdf file with the responsebody content but when i open the file it is blank.

my question is how can i create a new file with the same content as in response.

i tried the foll. code to convert the response

```
file  = new File("/home/abc.pdf");
            outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            byte[] contentInBytes = response.getBody().getBytes();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(contentInBytes));

            outputStream.write(contentInBytes);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get PDF file from web using java streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201790/how-to-get-pdf-file-from-web-using-java-streams)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a temporary `byte[]` array to store the entire response body before saving it to a file is wasteful. You want to write the response `InputStream` to the `OutputStream` of your file.

This can be done in few ways, one will be to use Guava's [`ByteStreams.copy()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.java) e.g.:

```
try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("abc.pdf")) {
    ByteStreams.copy(response.getBody(), out);
}
```